# How to Parsing JSON (Two Dimessional) array Object in android?

Tags: android, json

I have a stack with parsing JSON object in Android.

Here my JSON Data,

```
{
    STATUS: "200"
    ERROR: "false"
    SECRETKEY: "deb1d0b9a70a0ed682d2975b2a583c28"
    DATA: {
        stock: 2
        pins: [1]
        0: {
            id: "1"
            pin: "8172310874"
            serial: "0000000000100000"
            card_type: "10000"
            company: "FWIFI"
            expiry_date: "2016-01-01"
            invoice_id: "INVHQ/000001"
            order_id: "1"
            delivered: "0"
           }

       }
}
```

Here my parsing json object

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
    String secretKey = json.get("SECRETKEY").toString();
    JSONObject data_obj = new JSONObject("DATA");   //problem is here. It's go to catch block 
    JSONArray j_array = data_obj.getJSONArray("pins");
    Integer qty = j_array.length();
         for(int i = 0 ; i < j_array.length() ; i++){
               //here loop
         }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please pointing me how can I loop? I change this. But, error say like that.

***Value DATA of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject***

Comment: `{` is a `jsonObject`, not `jsonArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is not a jsonarray it is a jsonObject `{` ->represent the jsonObject and `[`->represents the jsonArray.so change to`JSONObject pin_Arr = json.getJSONObject("DATA");`

Answer (score 2):

You should get that `DATA` as a `JSONObject` and then get your `0` in turn as a JSONObject.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(value);
    String secretKey = json.get("SECRETKEY").toString();
    JSONArray pin_Arr = json.getJSONArray("DATA");   //problem is here. It's go to catch blcok 
    Integer qty = pin_Arr.length();
         for(int i = 0 ; i < pin_Arr.length() ; i++){
               JSONObject actor = pin_Arr.getJSONObject(i);
              String name = actor.getString("your data");
              // you can add your datahere   
         }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: DATA is a `JsonObect`, your code is not different with OP's code. it is completely wrong

Comment: I think, this JSONArray pin_Arr = json.getJSONArray("DATA");  must be like that JSONObject j_obj = json.JSONOBject("DATA");

Answer (score 1):

that's not a valid JSON ;)

After the key-value you need a comma and the keys have to be into declared into "..."

You can check if your JSON is valid on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com), an online validator.

Basically it should look like:

```
{
    "STATUS": 200,
    "ERROR": "false",
    "SECRETKEY": "deb1d0b9a70a0ed682d2975b2a583c28",
    "DATA": {
        "0": {
            "id": "1",
            "pin": "8172310874",
            "serial": "0000000000100000",
            "card_type": "10000",
            "company": "FWIFI",
            "expiry_date": "2016-01-01",
            "invoice_id": "INVHQ/000001",
            "order_id": "1",
            "delivered": "0"
        },
        "stock": 2,
        "pins": [
            1
        ]
    }
}
```

As soon as you have got something like that you can use GSON, Jackson or the standard JSONObject provided by android in order to access your JSON fields, objects and arrays as map through the keys that you have got in your JSON ("STATUS", "ERROR",...).

Answer (score 0):

## Why not use Json parser?

try :
   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple